# Regex to match numbers starting with 1, maximum 12 digits

Tags: regex

I am searching for a regular expression that matches any string that is:

1. A number which is greater than zero
2. The number has at least one digit
3. No more than 12 digits

I tried this one without success:

```
^[1-9][0-9]*{1,12}$
```

Comment: Can you have numbers that contain leading zeros but are greater than zero?

Comment: @SebastianProske Would be nice but does not have to be like that. Interesting point!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If numbers with leading zeros that are greater than zero are allowed, you can use `^(?!0+$)[0-9]{1,12}$` if the tool/language you use supports lookaheads. The lookahead is used to ensure that the number doesn't entirely consist of zeros.

Answer (score 2):

`^[1-9][0-9]{0,11}$`

Start with a single digit between 1-9, then have 0 to 11 occurrences of a digit between 0-9

Comment: Why do you have a capture group around the last 0-11 digits?

Comment: You're right, my mistake. I was testing something else with this expression and forgot to remove the group. Updated now!

Answer (score 2):

Use `^[1-9]\d{0,11}$`, which checks for a non-zero digit followed by zero to 11 digits.

Your regex had a quantifier `*` after the second character class, which would allow zero or more occurrence of a digit (which can be more than 11 digits). Also the quantifier `{1,12}` sets the minimum occurrence of preceding pattern as 1 and maximum occurrence as 12. So you had to avoid the `*` and set minimum and maximum as 0 and 11 respectively, since there was already a pattern for single digit.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the regular expression

```
    ^[1-9][0-9]*{1,12}$
```

is the star `*` used together with `{1,12}` as the star  `*`means *any number of repetitions of the previous symbol* whereas `{1,12}` means *one to twelve repetitions* - so the star `*` and `{a,b}` don't mix and must be used exclusively, not together.